# How to use autolayout to prevent overlapping of arbitrary number of dynamically created UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

How can I prevent multiple UIViews from overlapping when the number of UIViews isn't defined before hand? I don't really care where they are placed on screen as long as a certain padding definition is met.

Using autolayout seems the way to do it but I can't get it right.

I would probably need to have a loop

```
UIView *prevView = nil;
for (UIView *aView in [self subViews])
{
  // would really need to check foreach subview if this view isn't overlapping
  // lets assume just 2 views for simplicity
  if (CGRectIntersectsRect(aView.frame,prevView.frame))
  {
    // update the view frame
    // or update autolayout constraints
  }
}
// might need to call the function recursively if first pass wasn't successful
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific wants and needs you could:

1. Position a new subview correctly when creating it. If your subviews don't move you could easily write some logic to make a correct layout of the subviews.
2. Loop through your subviews as you suggests and relocate each overlapping subview until it's no longer overlapping:

   ```
   while(CGRectIntersectsRect(aView.frame, prevView.frame)){
       // Re-locate aView
       [aView setCenter: CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height))];
   }
   ```

   Downside is of course performance: with a lot of subviews it could take a while (and many randomly generated numbers) to find a free space.
   If you use this you should at least **make sure your app won't be stuck in an infinite loop**.
3. Divide the screen into fixed size blocks and use these blocks to position your views. If your subviews will never be bigger than 50 * 50, for example, divide the screen into x blocks of 50 * 50. You could keep track of these spaces with an array.